# `float array` does not name a type error

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Here is a minimum working code example that generates the error `‘MyMap’ does not name a type`

```
const int MAX_N = 4;

enum ENUM_POINTS{A=0, B, C, D};
float MyMap[MAX_N][MAX_N]={{0}};

MyMap[A][B]=140;
MyMap[B][C]=90;
MyMap[B][D]=85;

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is `gcc`. I think the error message/type does not fit the situation. Does anybody know why this type of error is generated by the compiler for the above error?

Comment: When you pass something to the compiler that isn't the C language, but just random letters in a text file, why do you expect it to behave in a certain predictable way? Essentially the compiler is just telling you "something is completely messed up at this line". Just leave it at that... If you crash your car into a concrete pillar, completely smashing the front to pieces, and then a light on the panel tells you "it is time to fill up the oil", then it is not exactly a meaningful task to dissect the wreck to find out why it gives that particular error.

Answer (score 7):

You can't have statements outside of functions, only declarations and definitions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already knew it! My question is why the compiler generates `‘MyMap’ does not name a type` error? I think it should generate another error type, don't you think so?

Comment: @Rasoul What other kind of error do you think you should get? The compiler sees an identifier, and tries to look it up as a type (i.e. type alias as created from `typedef`), and can't find such a type.

Comment: @Rasoul outside functions, it looks for type declarations in which the first "word" is a type, but MyMap is inherently not a type, so...

Comment: @Lưu: But the type of `MyMap` is already defined above the assignments. So I suppose that the type of `MyMap` has already defined when the compiler reaches to the assignments. Hence, the error `‘MyMap’ does not name a type` does not fit the situation I believe...

Comment: @Rasoul `MyMap` *have* a type, but it *isn't* a type. There's a difference between having something and being something.